# Compiling Gulp to Parent Folder

Tags: sass, gulp, pug

I know that this question has been asked before but the given answer     doesn't seem to working. I've checked the GULP documentation and GitHub Gulp as well. My Gulp refuses to compile to the specificed folder. Here is my project structure

```
Parent [contains gulpfile.js]
|_src
   |_assets
       |_jade
       |_sass
       |_scripts
```

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var pug = require('gulp-pug');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

// == PATH STRINGS ========
var paths = {
    typescript: './src/**/*.ts',
    pug: 'src/assets/pug/*.pug',
    sass: 'src/assets/sass/*.scss',
    distScripts: 'src/scripts',
    distPug: '../../src',
    distSass: 'src'
};

// == TYPESCRIPT ========
gulp.task('typescript', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.typescript)
        .pipe(ts({
            noImplicitAny: true,
            outFile: 'output.js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distTypescript));
});

// == pug ===============
gulp.task('pug', function() {
  gulp.src(paths.pug)
    .pipe(pug({}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../../src'))
});

// == SASS ==============
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.sass)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distSass));
});

// == COMPILE SYNCHRONOUSLY
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(paths.typescript, ['typescript']);
  gulp.watch(paths.pug, ['pug']);
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
});
```

I just want to compile my sass and pug files to the *src* files. Thank you so much for any help or assistance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've managed to answer this question myself. Thanks everyone. All I needed to do was specify direct paths instead of using universal selectors

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var pug = require('gulp-pug');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

// == PATH STRINGS ========
var paths = {
    typescript: './src/**/*.ts',
    pug: 'src/assets/pug/*.pug',
    sass: 'src/assets/sass/*.scss',
    distTypescript: 'src/scripts',
    distPug: 'src',
    distSass: 'src'
};

// == TYPESCRIPT ========
gulp.task('typescript', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.typescript)
        .pipe(ts({
            noImplicitAny: true,
            outFile: 'output.js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distTypescript));
});

// == pug ===============
gulp.task('pug', function() {
  gulp.src(paths.pug)
    .pipe(pug({}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distPug))
});

// == SASS ==============
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.sass)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distSass));
});

// == COMPILE SYNCHRONOUSLY
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(paths.typescript, ['typescript']);
  gulp.watch(paths.pug, ['pug']);
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
});
```

Comment: Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer